# Splunk message in a single string with filenames needs to split

Tags: split, z-index, splunk

Hi I have a splunk message that gets list of filenames with paths in a single string. I need to extract all the filenames into new line in a single row

Message:

```
/opt/test/files/matched/test1.txt, /src/files/log/test.log, /opt/main/unmatched/test2.txt
```

Need to get the files names for a id

```
ID        Filenames
1            test1.txt
             test.log
             test2.txt
2           <another list of names>
```

Tried using mvexpand but could not achieve it

```
| eval FileNames=mvindex(split(split(Sourcefiles,","), "/"),-1)| table Id, FileNames |mvexpand FileName
```

Answer (score 1):

While you might get `split` to work, `rex` is much easier.  This run-anywhere query is an example. The regex in `rex` extracts the filename from each path into a multi-value field.  Then, `mvjoin` combines them into a single line.

```
| makeresults | eval Sourcefiles="/opt/test/files/matched/test1.txt, /src/files/log/test.log, /opt/main/unmatched/test2.txt"
`comment("Above just sets up test data")`
| rex field=Sourcefiles max_match=0 "\/(?<FileName>\w+\.?\w*)(?:,|$)" 
| eval FileNames=mvjoin(FileName, " ")
```

Comment: your answer works whe i use makeresults, I get what I am looking for.. but in my search scenario the filenames are empty. Please find the attached image and let know your thoughts

Comment: Your example data was over-simplified so now the regex doesn't match the read data.  Try this regex: `\/(?<FileName>[\w\.]+)(?:,|$)`.